# Getting error when trying to run code in Google Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

I am getting the following error when running code on my localhost using Google Chrome.

**I am able to view the working code when using Safari but not when using Chrome!**

> 127.0.0.1/:55          GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/app.js/ net::ERR_ABORTED 500 (Internal Server Error) :5500/?task=#:1 Refused
> to execute script from 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/app.js/' because its
> MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type
> checking is enabled.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Task List</title>

    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css"
    />

    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/83486dfd83.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- removed, not important -->
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.js"
      integrity="sha256-3zlB5s2uwoUzrXK3BT7AX3FyvojsraNFxCc2vC/7pNI="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The error message shows a request to `/app.js/` (with a trailing slash) but that doesn't appear in your markup at all. Either what you've shown isn't your actual markup or something is redirecting the request for `app.js` to `app.js/` and your server is responding with a 500 error page

Comment: Hi Phil, when I changed it to /app.js/ from app.js, the code still doesn't work in Chrome (giving me the same error) and now the code doesn't work in Safari and gives me the following error:

Comment: [Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) (app.js, line 0)
[Error] Refused to execute http://localhost:5500/app.js/ as script because "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff" was given and its Content-Type is not a script MIME type.)

Comment: You misunderstood my comment. The error message does not align with the code you've shown in your question. I did not suggest making any changes at all

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this, this is my actual markup and the code did work (the accompanying app.js file) in Safari.

- Update, let me try clearing cache!

Comment: It did not work. I cleared cache in Chrome. I'm just wondering how this fails in Chrome but works in Safari? How do I check if something is redirecting me in Chrome?

Comment: What server are you running and how is it configured to serve static files like `app.js`?

Comment: Hi Phil, the problem was apparently not adding the bootstrap into the head. I have no idea why adding it worked. It made the error message go away and the JS code work but messed with my CSS.

Comment: That's difficult to believe. I wonder if you remove it again but make some other change it would also continue to work?

Comment: Yes I have no idea how it worked. I removed the code that he suggested to add and made the app.js spit out a console.log('Hello World') and it still worked.

Maybe adding the link he gave below and running it once did something even after removing?

When I added it and ran it the first time, it changed all my buttons to black color, overriding the material UI theme.

Comment: Thank you for assisting me, I know it is confusing without screenshots and stuff. I am also very new to JS.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i read the code and i find that do use bootstrap , but you dont add the links into head for the files of bootstarp :

```
<!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: Whether OP includes Bootstrap or not isn't relevant to the error message they're getting

Comment: AHMED! I added this code and it worked!

But now the colors are all somehow messed up, I will try fixing it on my own.